# Map - это карта или отображение?

Tags: java, коллекции, map, терминология

1. Map это карта или отображение?
2. Не пойму в чём фича названия "карта" или "отображение".
3. И как правильней?

Comment: Насколько я знаю, Map - это интерфейс

Comment: @cppquestions он имеет ввиду как правильно называть его на русском. Странно, никогда об этом не задумывался, так и называл, мап.

Comment: Если абстрагироваться от `java`, то по сути это словарь.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

В русскоязычной литературе это называется [Ассоциативный массив](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2)

Answer (score 8):

Ни "карта", ни "отображение" не использутся. Обычно пользуются англицизмом "мап" или реже "ассоциативный массив".

Терминология может меняться в разных сообществах.

Comment: Часто используется МАПА, кто любит женский род))))

Answer (score 3):

Если рассматривать как термин на английском, то "map"(*англ.*) имеет сл.значения:

1. Карта
2. Отображение
3. Схема, план

В IT используются разные произношения этого термина: мапа, мэп, отображение, ассоциативный массив, по сути означающее одно и то же: ассоциация ключа и значения на этот ключ.
Интересная "фича" в том, что для более простого понимания можно использовать как раз первые два вышеуказанных перевода: **Карта** "map" (*англ.*) **отображает** ключи на значения. По-моему наиболее понятно схожий объект назван в языке Python: "словарь". В любом словаре мы как раз и видим само слово (в д.сл. это ключ) и его значение на другом языке, т.е. отображение ключа на его значение.